# Youtube googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels stopped working for me today

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I have changed no code, but as of today:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&key=[MYKEY]
HEADERS [
"Authorization", "Bearer " + myToken
"Content-Type", "application/json" 
]
```

It is giving me this response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

My goal with by using this api call is to retrieve the token holder's youtubechannel name and id.
Just a day ago this was working (and has been working for over a year). I have changed no code related to this in my project.

for the `key=[MYKEY]` I have been using my CLIENT ID

Comment: Is it possible someone regenerated or deleted your API key? Did you check the Google API console?

Comment: I have never used an API-KEY in my code, only a client-id. I checked the clientid and secret, and both match up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a new APIKey, restricted it to youtube.v3.data, and change all query parameters of key=[clientid] to key=[apikey] and its working again, but it's disturbing that youtube api keeps quietly changing with no warning?